# I18n translation of model form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, internationalization, django-forms, translation

I have a form that I want to translate:

Models.py:

```
class Show(models.Model):
    discount_tickets = models.IntegerField("Discount Tickets")
    regular_tickets = models.IntegerField("Regular Tickets")
    afillate_price = models.IntegerField("Afillate Price")
    user_price = models.IntegerField("User Price")
    start_time = models.CharField("Event Time", max_length=20)
    sale_end_time = models.CharField("Sale End Time", max_length=20) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.discount_tickets)

class ShowForm(ModelForm):
    pass

    class Meta:
        model = Show
```

How can I translate the field names?

Comment: OP, you should have a read through [the translation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.utils.translation) as they are very clear on how to manage translation throughout your project

Answer (score 10):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Show(models.Model):
    discount_tickets = models.IntegerField(_("Discount Tickets"))
    regular_tickets = models.IntegerField(_("Regular Tickets"))
    afillate_price = models.IntegerField(_("Afillate Price"))
    user_price = models.IntegerField(_("User Price"))
    start_time = models.CharField(_("Event Time"), max_length=20)
    sale_end_time = models.CharField(_("Sale End Time"), max_length=20)
```

Comment: The [convention is to assign `ugettext_lazy` to the underscore character](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation); `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _` which makes it a little bit more readable.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony thank you for reminding me, I almost forgot that.